How to Serialize LockFreeBucket for Infinispan Cache in Bucket4j?
I'm trying to implement a rate limiter using Bucket4j and Infinispan. Below is the code I'm using to store LockFreeBucket objects in the Infinispan cache:
public boolean isRateLimited(String key) {

Bucket bucket = cacheManager.getCache("rate-limiter").get(key, 
Bucket.class);

    if (bucket == null) {
        bucket = bucketSupplier.get();
        Cache<String, Bucket> cache = cacheManager.getCache("rate-limiter");
        cache.put(key, bucket);
    }
    return !bucket.tryConsume(1);
}

When it tries to put the key i.e cache.put(key, bucket) I'm getting exception as org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:: Unable to marshall object of type [io.github.bucket4j.local.LockFreeBucket]] with root cause
java.io.NotSerializableException: io.github.bucket4j.local.LockFreeBucket
And below is my RemoteCacheManagerConfiugration
@Bean
public RemoteCacheManager getRemoteCacheManager() {

    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

configurationBuilder
    .addServer()
    .host("somehost")
    .port(11222)
    .marshaller(new JavaSerializationMarshaller())
    .addJavaSerialWhiteList("io.github.bucket4j.*")
    .security()
    .ssl()
    .sniHostName("infinispan")
    .trustStoreFileName("./cacerts 2")
    .trustStorePassword("changeit".toCharArray())
    .authentication()
    .username("some")
    .password("somepassword")
    .addContextInitializer(new CreateProtoImpl())
    .clientIntelligence(ClientIntelligence.BASIC);
    return new RemoteCacheManager(configurationBuilder.build());
}


LockFreeBucket does not implement java.io.Serializable. The simplest way would be with Protostream adapters, although it seems a complex class to serialize: https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/encoding/encoding.html#creating-protostream-adapter_marshalling
Are you using bucket4j-infinispan?

Yes I'm using bucket4j infispan

But LockFreeBucket is very big class in the example they have given example of UUID which can be easily initialized by string but in the case of LockFreeBucket it is quite complex

The link for the Infinispan doc contains all the methods supported for marshaling. LockFreeBucket has a method to convert to JSON, maybe it is possible to use it? Have you asked bucket4j dev for their recommendation? https://github.com/bucket4j/bucket4j/blob/master/bucket4j-core/src/main/java/io/github/bucket4j/local/LockFreeBucket.java#L583

Yup!!! It is working had to convert into bytes

First of all, why do you not use the existing built-in integration of Bucket4j with Infinispan?
If you do not trust official integration, that means that you ignore built-in distributed facilities, hence it is legal to always cast bucket to LocalBucket. LocalBucket provides all neccesary functionality for serialization and desiralization from/to both binary form and JSON compatible HashMap.
